# jQuery slider doesn't loop perfectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, animation, slider

Im currently having a problem with my background image slider. It works perfectly fine the first time it runs, but the second time it 'bumps' the picture to the right when visible, instead of doing that when not visible. I hope some of you would take the time to look into this. Would be appreciated.

The code I'm using :

html part:

```
<div id="logo">
    <img src="images/5.jpg">
    <img src="images/6.jpg">
    <img src="images/7.jpg">
    <img src="images/8.jpg">
    <img src="images/9.jpg">
    <img src="images/10.jpg">
    <img src="images/11.jpg">
</div>
```

css part:

```
#logo img {
    min-height: 100%;
    width:110%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top:0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var slideshow = 0;
var currentImageIndex = 0;

var nextImage = function () {
    var $imgs = $('#logo > img');
    currentImageIndex++;

    if (currentImageIndex > $imgs.length) {
        currentImageIndex = 1;
    }

    $('#logo > img:nth-child(' + currentImageIndex + ')')
        .fadeIn(function () { //.fadeIn() .show()

        $(this).animate({
            left: '-75px'
        }, 8000, 'linear')

        $(this).delay(100).fadeOut(nextImage), 1200; //.fadeOut() .show()

        $(this).css({
            left: '0px'
        })
    })
};
```

And it's triggered when clicked:

```
$( ".hexagoncontainer7" ).click(function() {
  if (slideshow == 0) {
    nextImage();
    slideshow=1;
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm out of time for now, but here's a starting point fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/3aaLa976

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things to improve here. Hopefully this will give you a good start:

1. Currently, you're searching the DOM for your images twice upon each `nextImage()` call:

   `var $imgs = $('#logo > img');` and `$('#logo > img:nth-child(' + currentImageIndex + ')')`.

   Searching the DOM is computationally expensive, and you should do it only when necessary. Instead, if you need to work with the same elements over and over again (as you do with your images), select them once, and store them in variables for later use.
2. In the following lines:

   ```
   $(this).animate({left: '-75px'}, 8000, 'linear')
   $(this).delay(100).fadeOut(nextImage), 1200; //.fadeOut() .show()
   $(this).css({left: '0px'})
   ```

   a few things need to be fixed. First, line 3 removes any offset on your images left over from the previous pass. You want this step at the beginning of your sequence of steps (even before `fadeIn`), not at the end where its effect will be delayed.

   Next, you do not need the `delay(100)` call before `fadeOut()`, because [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) lets you provide a callback which will be called once the animation completes. Supply your fadeOut code in the callback.

   Also, notice that [`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) first takes `duration` as a parameter, then the `complete` callback, i.e. your call should be `fadeOut(1200, nextImage)` if you want the fade-out effect to execute over 1200 ms.

   Finally, jQuery lets you [chain functions](http://www.jquery-tutorial.net/introduction/method-chaining/), which will save you a few calls to the jQuery function.
3. You should consider [removing](http://api.jquery.com/off/) the click handler on `#logo` after the first click, to avoid unexpected behavior when users click more than once.
4. At the moment your images are stacked in reverse order over each other. You need to hide all but the first one with CSS.
5. Don't forget the semicolons and name your functions as actions, i.e. `loadNextImage` - your code will be easier to read.

Here is a working fiddle with all the changes: http://jsfiddle.net/stiliyan/4bo0258p/ (forked from the one isherwood posted)

In case you want to learn more best practices with jQuery I strongly recommend the [Try jQuery](http://try.jquery.com/) course by CodeSchool.

Comment: Thank you, helped alot! I do want to learn more about jQuery ofcourse, and I already followed the try jQuery course some time ago. I know my way around now to make things work, but not optimal. I guess it is just a matter of time and practice.